# How to disable all tasks in a Gradle group?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Gradle tasks can be grouped, like so:

```
task spotbugs(type: SpotBugsTask, dependsOn: "assemble", group: "verification")
```

However, I've yet to find any practical use for the group. I'm looking to disable all tasks in the group `verification`, which doesn't seem to be possible. I'm aware that I can skip a specific task with `-x`, or that I can use `onlyIf` with a custom property or disable the task using `enabled = false`; my question is whether or not I can disable the group?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to dynamically disable tasks, you need to take into consideration what tasks Gradle determined to execute, and then disable any tasks that match your criteria. To do this, you can use the [task graph](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html):

```
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    graph.allTasks.findAll { it.group == 'verification' }.each { it.enabled = false }
}
```

Now, if any tasks in the group `verification` are scheduled for execution, they'll be disabled (skipped).